# Как остановить цикл в автокликере?

Tags: java, javafx, циклы, while, awt

Как остановить цикл `while` с помощью той же кнопки ("F12"), и почему программа зависает на моменте, когда должен начаться цикл?

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    int delayVal;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        window = stage;
        window.setTitle("Автокликер");
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icondefault.png")));
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 50);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(50);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(2);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                delayVal = newValue.intValue();
            }
        });
        GridPane.setConstraints(slider, 0, 1);
        Label chastota = new Label("Частота клика");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        GridPane.setConstraints(chastota, 0, 0);
        grid.getChildren().addAll(chastota, slider);
        scene = new Scene(grid, 200, 100);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        while (true) {
            scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                    if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F12")) {
                        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                        robot.delay(delayVal);
                        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                        robot.delay(delayVal);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему добавление обработчика `KeyEvent` находится в бесконечном цикле `while (true)`? Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо это просто за гранью добра и зла.

Comment: Да, скорее всего это вы что-то не понимаете, я проделывал еще более ужаснее вещи, чем это. Плохо понимаю суть всего этого, но на ошибках учатся. Теперь буду знать что так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.show();
Robot robot = new Robot();
while (true) {
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F12")) {
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(delayVal);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(delayVal);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Тут в бесконечном цикле добавляется обработчик. Это неправильно. Надо добавить обработчик один раз, и затем уже в бесконечном цикле его крутить. Только надо ещё придумать как сделать точку остановки цикла. Например, останавливать цикл, если нажата кнопка **F11**.

Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
window.show();
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    public void call() throws Exception {
        while (getState() != State.CANCELED) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.delay(delayVal);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.delay(delayVal);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyEvent.F12)) {
            new Thread(task).start();
        }
        else if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyEvent.F11)) {
            task.cancel();
        }
    }
```

Лучше вызывать в другом потоке, чтобы GUI не зависал.

Comment: @Regent не подскажешь, как ты отформатировал код? Сам пробелы расставлял или есть какая более удобная штука на so?

Comment: Для JS-кода вполне подходит автоматическое форматирование в [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), но, думаю, и с Java-кодом он бы справился. Я же, как странный человек, действительно вручную расставляю отступы. Хоть и не по клавише пробела тыкаю, а использую _Ctrl+V_ с 4 пробелами в буфере, но всё же.

Comment: А мне необходимо, что бы именно на F12 и включалось и выключалось. Я нашел похожую проблему вот тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615451/robot-mousepress-auto-clicker-how-to-make-it-stop
Но не понял, как это реализовать

Comment: Ну тогда тебе надо добавить счетчик, который считал бы, сколько раз  кликнулась клавиша F12. И если этот счетчик кратен 2, то выключать цикл, иначе включать

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, хорошо, с этим я потом решу. Сейчас попробовал запустить ваш код, но он не работает.Пробовал изменить на вот так:
public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F12")) {
                    
                     new Thread(task).start();
                } else if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F11")) {
                    task.cancel();
но так тоже не работает.

Comment: А что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Не работает цикл. Нажимаю f12, ничего не происходит

Comment: Попробуй залогировать, заходит ли он у тебя вообще в эту ветку if'а